# Does Linux perform buffering twice when hosting a VM?

Tags: linux, kvm, ram, buffer

I ran a KVM VM on my CentOS host and found that after performing a HDD-intensive operation, it used all of the host's memory I assigned to it. However, `free` on the guest suggests that the memory's only cached. Does the host also cache the hard disk blocks the guest used? If so, can I somehow disable HDD buffering in the guest, assuming that the VM host is going to perform it anyway?

Comment: you usually can't trust anything that a guest tells you about itself.

Comment: You can choose KVM/qemu's i/o and caching methods to tune performance.  See, for example, the serverfault question http://serverfault.com/questions/425607/kvm-guest-io-is-much-slower-than-host-io-is-that-normal